# Flagging an Address based on a conditional occurrences

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-conditions

I’d like to create a new 'Hit?' column that returns `Hit` if a SiteLocation has a `1` in column 'Required?' and does not have `Pie-Active` in column 'Product-Status'.

Here's the starting table:

| SiteAddress | Required? | Product-Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 something street | 1 | Cake-active |
| 1234 something street | 0 | Pie-active |
| 1234 something street | 0 | Cake-inactive |
| 1234 something street | 0 | KeyLime-active |
| 1234 something street | 0 | Vanilla Sundae-active |
| 1234 something street | 0 | Pie-inactive |
| 567 other street | 0 | Cake-active |
| 567 other street | 1 | Cake-inactive |
| 567 other street | 0 | KeyLime-inactive |

In this example, SiteLocation `567 other street` would get flagged as `hit` since it contains at least one `1` and does not contain any `Pie-active`. See below for what I'm hoping to create:

| SiteAddress | Required? | Product-status | Hit? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 something street | 1 | Cake-active | No Hit |
| 1234 something street | 0 | Pie-active | No Hit |
| 1234 something street | 0 | Cake-inactive | No Hit |
| 1234 something street | 0 | KeyLime-active | No Hit |
| 1234 something street | 0 | Vanilla Sundae-active | No Hit |
| 1234 something street | 0 | Pie-inactive | No Hit |
| 567 other street | 0 | Cake-active | Hit |
| 567 other street | 1 | Cake-inactive | Hit |
| 567 other street | 0 | KeyLime-inactive | Hit |

Although `1234 something street` has `1` in column 'Required?', it also has `Pie-active` so this is an example where the condition is not satisfied.

I understand that I need to use logic similar to this:

```
condition1 = Required? == 1
condition2 = Product-Status != 'Pie-Active'
RelevantAddresses  = distinct SiteAddresses satisfying condition 1 and condition 2
New Column: Hit? = if SiteAddress is in RelevantAddresses, Hit, otherwise No Hit
```

Note that `SiteAddress`, `Required?` and `Product-Status` are all alias names (I had to manually create them) so I believe I need to create sub queries to access these fields.

I attempted to create this query but I'm running into a bit of a wall. I have this so far:

```
DECLARE @Required? as bit
DECLARE @COND1 as bit

SET @COND1 = CASE WHEN @Required? = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

SELECT @Required? = (SELECT 
CASE
WHEN
.... subquery ... as Required?

    
SET @COND2 = CASE WHEN @Product-Status != 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

SELECT @Product-Status = (SELECT
CASE 
WHEN 
.... subquery ... as Product-Status
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
select t1.*, 
       case when tmp.SiteAddress is not null 
            then 'Hit'
            else 'No Hit'
       end as [Hit?]
from your_table t1
left join 
(
  select SiteAddress
  from your_table
  group by SiteAddress
  having max([Required?]) = 1  
     and sum(case when [Product-status] = 'Pie-Active' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
) tmp on t1.SiteAddress = tmp.SiteAddress
```

or even shorter do it with window functions:

```
select *, 
       case when sum(case when [Product-status] = 'Pie-Active' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by SiteAddress) = 0
                 and max([Required?]) over (partition by SiteAddress) = 1  
            then 'Hit'
            else 'No Hit'
       end as [Hit?]
from your_table
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0bd2d7/6)

Comment: Thanks, really like the window function approach. Need to learn more about these functions. In the first example, tmp is just how you named the sub query right? It doesn’t have any special meaning? Appreciate the response

Comment: Yes, `tmp` is the table alias name. You need to name you subqueries. Thats all.